# How to modify the visibility of different layer in a figure plotted by Matlab when I finished the plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot, visibility

A figure file is saved. When several lines are intersected, I want to make one of the line visible. How should I modify the different layer of the lines without re-plotting the figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `uistack` (see [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistack.html)). For example, after:

```
figure
hold on
hblue=plot([1 2],[3 4],'b','LineWidth',5);
hred=plot([1 2],[4 3],'r','LineWidth',5);
```

the red line is on top (and the blue line would not be seen if the the red line covered it). Then, if you use `uistack(hblue,'top')`, the blue line is brought to the top. Other options to reorder plots, instead of `top`, are `up`, `down`, and `bottom`. You can optionally specify the number of steps `up` or `down` (e.g. `uistack(h,'up',2)` to move a handle two layers up - though no need in my simple example).

If, as you say, the 'figure file is saved', and you don't have the handles for the plots, (`hblue` and `hred` in my example), after loading the plot, you can get the handles using `get(gca,'children')`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, try to use [`hold on`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) before plotting...

Comment: Sorry, maybe I mislead you. What I meant to do is to modify the visibility of different layers. For example, I have layer 1 and layer 2 in the figure. Now, layer 1 is covered by layer 2 and thus cannot be seen. What I want to do is to modify the visibility of layer 1 so that I can see the lines or figures in layer 1.

Comment: Actually no. Suppose we use y1=plot(1:t,x1) and y2=plot(1:t,x2), 'hold on' can maintain two lines in the same figure. But if y1 and y2 have intersections and we plot y1 at first, then, at the intersection point, y1 will be covered by y2. What I want to do now is to let y1 visible. So I am wondering if I need to change the visibility of different layers here.